# RedissonDelayedQueue stop transfer timeout elements to destination queue

Tags: java

After using for a while, the RedissonDelayedQueue stop work。All added elements are backlogged in the queue，even if many elements have already timeout。
When I restarted the application，all the elements will transfer to the destination queue。
I used

pubsub numsub redisson_delay_queue_channel:{xxx}

"redisson_delay_queue_channel:{xxx}"
(integer) 0

find that redission client and redis subscriptions are disconnected, it caused RedissonDelayedQueue stop work. All added elements are backlogged in the queue, When I restarted the application，all the elements will transfer to the destination queue.

My Redisson version is 3.11.0

This instance is used as a field in the class，this instance should not have been removed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.